# Pandas: compute daily statistics when chunking

Tags: pandas, postgresql, resampling, chunking

Consider a postgres table where for the date 2022-05-01 we have 200 values for various times:

```
time                        value                                                                                
2022-05-01 00:17:20+00:00  17175 
2022-05-01 13:33:56+00:00  18000
...
```

I need to read data chunk by chunk with a chunk_size = 50. Doing resampling and aggregation to compute daily statistics, results in the four same indexes where each one contains a portion of the aggregated value.

```
with engine.connect().execution_options(stream_results=True) as conn:
for chunk_df in pd.read_sql(query, engine, chunksize=50):
    chunk_df.index = pd.to_datetime(chunk_df.time, utc=pytz.utc)
    chunk_df.sort_index(inplace=True)
    result_df = chunk_df.resample('1D').agg('sum')

time                        value                                                                                
2022-05-01 00:00:00+00:00  52175 


time                        value                                                                                
2022-05-01 00:00:00+00:00  12001 


time                        value                                                                                
2022-05-01 00:00:00+00:00  3506 


time                        value                                                                                
2022-05-01 00:00:00+00:00  45623
```

I was wondering is there any solution that directly computes the correct aggregated value. In other words, how we can set the chunk size according to the time interval of the resampling process.

```
time                        value                                                                                
2022-05-01 00:00:00+00:00  113305
```

Answer (score 1):

If I got what you want right, a query like this should do the trick:

```
select date_trunc('day', time), sum(value) from table_name group by 1;
```

You can also add

- `order by 1 asc/desc` to sort it
- `where date_trunc('day', time) = '2020-03-16 00:00:00'` to filter by date

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a large table with dates ranging from 2009-01-01 until now and I wanna compute summary statistics for different resolutions such as `1H` and `1D`. Moreover, it contains over 20 fields where for each field we need to compute different aggregations such as `mean` and `sum`. So, handling these inside a query would be very hard .

Comment: I'd argue that computing aggregates would be faster on PG side compared to fetching the data and then wrangling it on the Py side, also you can `select avg(field), sum(field) ... ` in a single query with the desired time resolution. But understandable if you want a Py-side solution

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'll try to do such aggregations in PG-side. But what about other agg functions such as `last()` and `first()`?

Comment: Not sure about how exactly last and first work within pandas, but it should be pretty easy to achieve with `limit` and `order`. There's a bunch of handy aggregate functions in PG https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-aggregate.html (do scroll the page, there's multiple tables), and window functions might be useful too https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-window.html